# Server library is trying to load the js file as "text/html" on the cloud

Tags: reactjs, cloud, openshift, content-type, serve

I have a react typescript vite application and the build and run commands are as follows:

```
"build": "tsc && vite build",
"start:prod": "serve -s ./dist -p 8080"
```

It works just fine locally, without any problems, but in the cloud (using openshift) it gives me an error message:

**Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

I have an additional route for this microservice in openshift but I have to set the base in the vite.config.ts to be './' then it successfully get the files from the server but with an improper content-type.

I have also set the resolve extensions in the vite.config.ts but it didn't help.

Any ideas what could have caused this error?

Comment: What does the HTTP Request & Response look like ? Is there any redirections or different Accept headers ? Specific file extensions can be mapped to a certain MIME types in web servers. I assume OpenShift uses a webserver to host your static files too, have you looked at that webservers extension -> MIME type mapping ? It could also be a typo on your end that the webserver in openshift misinterpreted ?

Comment: It's a problem in the backend. There are two possible reasons: (1) the file isn't found and the backend returns a default error page instead. (2) there is an error in the backend's configuation so that for `js` files a wrong `Content-Type` header is sent. I assume it's (1) ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your backend API with a `Content-Type` header as `text/javascript` on this file (or all

You can see it with Chrome debug, panel Network to look how the ressource is requested.

Comment: I dont have a backend api to serve the static files. The serve library suppose to handle this.